# Make spin.js work with submit buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, spin.js

An issue thats been plaguing me for some time now. I cant get spin.js to work on submit buttons.

Heres a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSDGx/24/

If you comment out the submit button and instead allow the div then it works fine.

Thanks.

For reference:

```
<input type="submit" id="spin">

var spinner;    
var opts = {
lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
length: 5, // The length of each line
width: 2, // The line thickness
radius:5, // The radius of the inner circle
corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
rotate: 58, // The rotation offset
direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
color: '#fff', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
speed: 0.9, // Rounds per second
trail: 100, // Afterglow percentage
shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
top: '57%', // Top position relative to parent
left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
};
var target = document.getElementById('spin');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
$(target).data('spinner', spinner);
```

Comment: inputs aren't meant to contain other elements

Comment: You know what, thats the perfect result. It makes sense to me now why it doesn't work. I shall look for another method. Many thanks for pointing it out. Sometimes it takes someone pointing out the obvious to see it.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in a comment, submit buttons aren't meant to contain other elements.

This poses the issue with the question.

To get around this I have wrapped the submit button in a div with the same width and height.

```
<div id="wrap">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<button>` element instead, which by default acts as submit button:
http://jsfiddle.net/fgnass/q6ou3dt7/